# I am having issues with moment and angular filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs

This worked before the jsfiddle update and now it doesn't work. Any help would be welcome.

Here is the HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    {{ date | date: 'MM-dd-yy' }} <br/> <br/>

    {{ date | date: 'MMM-dd-yyyy' }} <br/> <br/>

    {{ date | date: 'MMMM-dd-yyyy' }} <br/> <br/>

    {{ d | date: 'MM/dd/yy' }} <br/> <br/>

    {{ d | date: 'MMM/dd/yyyy' }}

</div>
```

... and here is the Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.constant("moment", moment);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.d = new Date();
    $scope.date = new moment();
    $scope.getRandomDate = function(){
        var year = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2014;
        var month = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) ;
        var day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31);
        return moment([year, month, day]).toDate();
   };
   $scope.date = $scope.getRandomDate(); 

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/tkchx8me/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the module `angularMoment` as a dependency to your app module

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularMoment']);
```

Answer (score 1):

**All you need to do is use the `https` version of the `moment.min.js` in your external dependencies for JSFiddle.**

If you look in the browser console in your original fiddle, you will see this:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/galnova/tkchx8me/8/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.6.0/moment.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So, all you need to do is serve your moment dependency over HTTPS.

This is the only change I made to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w2u6LL6z/

Now, it's working!